# Showing Notice: Undefined property: wpdb::$insertid in D:\wamp\www\wordpress-4.7.1\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 684

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to get last inserted id to update table based on this id. For that I used $wpdb->insert_id for getting the last inserted id. But get this issue
Notice: Undefined property: wpdb::$insertid in D:\wamp\www\wordpress-4.7.1\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 684

this is my code. Someone please help

```
$parent_id=$template_load_data['id'];
         $wpdb->insert( 'wp_rxl_templates', array(
                'template_name' => $_POST['template_name_custom'],
                'template_content' => $post_content,
                'created_date' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
                'status' => 'active',
                'default_template'=>'false',
                'parent_template_id'=>''.$parent_id.'',
            ));
            $result_id = $wpdb->insertid;
 $result_data = "select wp_rxl where status ='active' NOT (id = '$result_id')";
```

Comment: It's `$wpdb->insert_id`

Comment: Thanks you its working now. I have one more doubt. how can update the table based on this id. the scenario is i need to insert this row as active and all other row expect last inserted row need to be inactive.

Comment: @Mittul yes I used

Comment: "select wp_rxl where status ='active' NOT (id = '$result_id')";

Comment: is this correct?

Comment: i have one row as active template which is a default one. When user select that active template  it will be inactive and new one will be created as active template with the parent id of that default template.. this is the scenario..is this query correct it this case?

Comment: this comes when I select the template

Comment: `update wp_rxl set status ='inactive'` // first we are inactivating all

Comment: `update wp_rxl set status = 'active' where id = $result_id` // now we are activating the last inserted template.

Comment: thank you so much this is the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrote it as wrong. Check below:

You have to use `$wpdb->insert_id` instead `$wpdb->insertid`.

```
$parent_id=$template_load_data['id'];
         $wpdb->insert( 'wp_rxl_templates', array(
                'template_name' => $_POST['template_name_custom'],
                'template_content' => $post_content,
                'created_date' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
                'status' => 'active',
                'default_template'=>'false',
                'parent_template_id'=>''.$parent_id.'',
            ));
            $result_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
 $result_data = "select wp_rxl where status ='active' NOT (id = '$result_id')";
```

Comment: Thank you, its working fine now

Comment: Thats good. Mark it as accepted and do upvote please. Glad to help.

Comment: sure, I will do